# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException with all the Hibernate entity classes for ehcache

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ehcache

I am using  version "1.7.0_79". 
Getting the following Exception

> ```
> 2016-11-17 16:42:54,127 : ERROR: net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory - Disk Write of
> ```
>
> data_member_keys failed: 
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor1 cannot be cast
>   to sun.reflect.SerializationConstructorAccessorImpl
>         at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:113)
>         at `enter code here`sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:331)
>         at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1376)
>         at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
>         at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:493)
>         at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
>         at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1133)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
>         at net.sf.ehcache.util.MemoryEfficientByteArrayOutputStream.serialize(MemoryEfficientByteArrayOutputStream.java:97)
>         at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.serializeElement(DiskStorageFactory.java:405)
>         at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.write(DiskStorageFactory.java:384)
>         at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory$DiskWriteTask.call(DiskStorageFactory.java:485)
>         at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory$PersistentDiskWriteTask.call(DiskStorageFactory.java:1088)
>         at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory$PersistentDiskWriteTask.call(DiskStorageFactory.java:1072)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

jpa.xml

```
<bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.abc.xyz" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</prop>
                <!-- should be turned off in production -->
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>

                <!-- This is the provider for Ehcache provided by Hibernate, using the "old" SPI -->
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">/ehcache.xml</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true"</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>


            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ehcache>
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"
           maxElementsInMemory="50000"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="true"/>

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
           maxElementsInMemory="50000"
           eternal="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="120"
           timeToLiveSeconds="120"
           overflowToDisk="true"
           diskPersistent="false"
               diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
            />

    <defaultCache
            maxElementsInMemory="50000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="120"
            timeToLiveSeconds="120"
            overflowToDisk="true"
            diskPersistent="false"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
            />

</ehcache>
```

Does anyone know any solution for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code you are using that creates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a class loader issue.

The only way this error can occur is if the class you are currently serializing is from a class loader that doesn't see the `SerializationConstructorAccessorImpl` used by the current serializer.

I can't tell anything more without knowing the environment where you are experiencing this error.

And my guess is that you are using JDK 1.6.

Comment: No I am using  version "1.7.0_79".